# Doctrine Paginator Foreach very slow

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, pagination

I am using doctrine in my symfony2 project.

I have a table Event and a table Photo. One event can have one or more photos, and a photo is related to one event.

Here is one of my dql queries :

```
    $dql = "
    SELECT e, (e.views * 0.1) + (e.likes * 0.9) as ratingEvent
    FROM WevseenMainBundle:Event e
    INNER JOIN e.photos p
    INNER JOIN e.firstPhoto fp
    WHERE fp.date BETWEEN :dateA AND :dateB
    AND p.lat BETWEEN :latA AND :latB
    AND ( p.lng > :lngA AND p.lng < :lngB )
    AND e.status = 'open'
    GROUP BY e
    HAVING COUNT(p.id) >= :minCountPhotos
    ORDER BY ratingEvent DESC
    ";

    $query = $em->createQuery($dql)
    ->setParameters($parameters)
    ->setFirstResult($firstEntry) // 0
    ->setMaxResults($numberOf); // 10

    $paginatorEvents = new Paginator($query, true);
```

With something like 11500 events and 160 000 photos, the query is very slow (more than 10 seconds), it is coming from the

```
GROUP BY e
HAVING COUNT(p.id) >= :minCountPhotos
```

Without this, it's fast.

I checked the sf2 profiler and it says that :

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT e0_.id) AS sclr0 FROM Event e0_ INNER JOIN Photo p1_ ON e0_.id = p1_.event_id INNER JOIN Photo p2_ ON e0_.firstPhoto_id = p2_.id WHERE p2_.date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND p1_.lat BETWEEN ? AND ? AND (p1_.lng > ? AND p1_.lng < ?) AND e0_.status = 'open' GROUP BY e0_.id, e0_.name, e0_.description, e0_.nb_photos, e0_.views, e0_.viewsEventPhotos, e0_.votes, e0_.rating, e0_.likes, e0_.up, e0_.down, e0_.status, e0_.end, e0_.time, e0_.averageTimeEvent, e0_.averageTimePhotos, e0_.averageTimeEventAndPhotos, e0_.needInstagramUpdate, e0_.origin, e0_.featured, e0_.firstPhoto_id HAVING COUNT(p1_.id) >= ?
Parameters: [Object(DateTime), Object(DateTime), '-42.93442389074508', '73.48078267112892', '-180', '180', '2']

Time: 2029.33 ms

    SELECT DISTINCT e0_.id AS id0, e0_.views * 1 + e0_.likes * 0 AS sclr1 FROM Event e0_
INNER JOIN Photo p1_ ON e0_.id = p1_.event_id INNER JOIN Photo p2_ ON e0_.firstPhoto_id = p2_.id WHERE p2_.date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND p1_.lat BETWEEN ? AND ? AND (p1_.lng > ? AND p1_.lng < ?) AND e0_.status = 'open' GROUP BY e0_.id, e0_.name, e0_.description, e0_.nb_photos, e0_.views, e0_.viewsEventPhotos, e0_.votes, e0_.rating, e0_.likes, e0_.up, e0_.down, e0_.status, e0_.end, e0_.time, e0_.averageTimeEvent, e0_.averageTimePhotos, e0_.averageTimeEventAndPhotos, e0_.needInstagramUpdate, e0_.origin, e0_.featured, e0_.firstPhoto_id HAVING COUNT(p1_.id) >= ? ORDER BY sclr1 DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

Time: 6179.01 ms
```

which are the two queries that takes time.
How can I improve this ?

**UPDATE, SOLUTION:**

changed

```
GROUP BY e
```

with

```
GROUP BY e.id
```

Comment: Perhaps only at the time the foreach is entered, the query will be executed because it's the first time it is needed. The query just takes eight seconds.

Comment: I thought about that but I have about 11000 Events and 160 000 photos, isn't 8 seconds a bit exaggerated ?

Comment: Hmm, how should I answer that? Perhaps there is a written contract between the Doctrine and the Database and it's written down which times are acceptable and when it takes longer you can get your money back or sue someone? :D Things take the time they need, this is a computer, damn stupid only told to do what to do. I don't think these machines have any feelings telling them that they are not fast enough and then they try to speed up things.

Comment: @httpete No, it seems to be a correct behaviour since you have alot of objects to hydrate. You may want to try with `$query->setHydratationMode(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is executed only when you iterate on the paginator.
You should copy the translated SQL request and profile it outside of Doctrine, chances are it will take 8 seconds to execute. And chances are it will be much faster once you add some wisely chosen indexes to your tables.

Comment: I tried with the SQL translated query and it's taking about 1s.

Comment: For all requests ? Without query cache ? I think Doctrine can execute up to 3 requests for a pagination like this. One for the total count, one for the ids and one for the data.

Comment: I used echo $query->getSQL(); and it is 10 times faster than doctrine...it might be the hydratation that takes so long

Comment: Without the HAVING, it is very fast. How come ?

Comment: You should give more information on your database schema, check symfony2 profiler for the 3 queries that take time and paste them here with their execution times.

Comment: Ohhh, i think, i have found it : I have to GROUP BY e.id and NOT GROUP BY e ! It's fast now :)